# Unable to get English-languages reviews using Yelp API

Tags: php, yelp

I am trying to use the Yelp API to get a list of english-language reviews using a variety of search terms, such as 'food', 'hotel', etc. I only get non-english reviews, despite the fact that I'm including the lang and lang_filter parameters.

Here, without any oAuth stuff, is the general url I am requesting from my application:

http://api.yelp.com/v2/search?lang=en&lang_filter=true&term=food&bounds=52.261155,4.610155|52.479116,5.067567

The bounds parameter narrows my search to around Amsterdam in The Netherlands.

I've, of course, tried many url request variations, using city, state instead of bounds for location, removing the lang_filter param, adding country code filter, etc.
Does anyone know how I can get only english-language reviews?

Strangely, if I go to Yelp's website and do the search for "food" for Amsterdam, I get ONLY english results, so I know those english articles are there.

Answer (score 0):

From Yelp Support:

we do not currently have a way to restrict the snippet text to a specific language unfortunately.  This is true of the site in general right now including www, not just the API.